# How do you run java code on JBossEWS application?

Tags: java, sockets, openshift

I want to run a simple java code on my JBossEWS application, the only thing the code does is create a socket on the port 50 000 and waits for connections, then it just outputs the ip of the client.

So far what I've done was copy the file with the java code (ServerSocket.java) to the folder src/main/java and pushed it to the server through git

but it doesn't automatically run I think.. what changes do I need to make? Or what am I doing wrong?

Thank you in advance,
DavidN

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To run your app on the OpenShift you need to create Maven project then push it with git and after that it will deployed on the server. [Java migrating to OpenShift.](https://blog.openshift.com/how-to-migrate-your-java-app-to-openshift/)

Run `rhc tail your_app`  to see log and discover how your app behaves.

Sure you will get `java.net.SocketException: Permission denied` . Check OpenShift blog for sockets details as it allows 8000 port for websocket .

Comment: I've tried creating two different maven based projects: JBossEWS and JBoss EAP.. after adding the source code file i've used git but nothing happened, maybe the folder i'm putting my java file (src/main/java) is wrong or I don't have permission to open a socket on a port that I want?? in this case port 50 000

Comment: I've done that, the result was too long for a comment so i've put that on pastebin:

http://pastebin.com/PhMkRzkC

It didn't mention any socketexception.. is the folder src/main/java/ the correct one to put my files with the java code? Sorry for troubling you and thank you for the help

Comment: Yes scr/main/java is rigth path to put your clasess. Also try to write logger int your class to see if it executed or simple Syste.out.printLn if it not apper in console then it probem of build path or maven options.

Comment: Solved, I was able to log a test message. Thank you for the help provided.